# Transition Expands the Page

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I have a problem regarding CSS3's transitioning. As seen in the snippet of my CSS file below, I have made a footer slide up whenever it is toggled active (I do this using jQuery).

Whenever it becomes active, it pushes the content of the website upwards until it finishes its transition, at which point the content slides back down. It looks like the page expands, but this should not happen because of the position attribute. Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```css
.footer {
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -130px;
  background-color: #333;
  transition: bottom 250ms ease-out;
}
.footer-active {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: The element that is fixed is at the bottom of the page.  When viewed in a browser, when activated it pushes the content above it to display.  Try  `z-index: 1` to display it above the content.

Comment: Your idea did not work, but thank you for the suggestion. The element is absolute, so it should move independently from the other content, and so it  should not push the other content in order to make room.

Comment: Add working code snippet please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bmjohansen/tht527gr/

Here is a working demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. It seems whenever the element moves, the window will automatically scroll to the element's position. I fixed the problem by inserting `overflow: hidden` into the html's and body's CSS rule.